# Font size of the placeholder

Tags: ios, fonts, uitextfield

I want to draw the text placeholder in a textfield the same size as the text itself

however, i see a small jump in the background of the textfield, because they are not of the same size.

I subclassed the UITextField class and overridden the method

```
-(void)drawPlaceholderInRect:(CGRect)rect{
     [[self placeholder] drawInRect:rect withAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor blueColor]  , NSFontAttributeName : self.font}];
}
```

how do i make sure this has the same font size as the textfield's font size?

Answer (score 0):

By default, the `placeholder` and the `text` of a `UITextField` are the same font size.

If you set the text field's text using the `attributedText` property set with the different font, then set the text field's `attributePlaceholder` property and use the same font.

There is no need to override the `drawPlaceholderInRect:` method for this. This assumes you only need to support iOS 6.0 and later.

```
NSDictionary *attrs = @{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor blueColor], NSFontAttributeName : self.font };
NSAttributedString *str = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:someText attributes:attrs];
someTextField.attributePlaceholder = str;
```

Comment: I wanted the placeholder a different color , and that is why i did this, i dont want to go over each textfield i have in my interfacebuilder and adjust all the attributes, i want it to be this way by class

Comment: Using the `attributedPlaceholder` lets you set the color, font, and other attributes.

Comment: can you give me an example please? i also want to make it centered in the text field

Comment: It's much like the code you posted except use those attributes to create an `NSAttributedString`. Then assign the attributed string to the `attributedPlaceholder` property.

Comment: See my updated answer. Add any other attributes you might want.